# Retrieve and load playlists from YouTube

Tags: javascript, performance, youtube

I have this code I am using in a private project.  The following is a snippet of code I use to retrieve and load playlists from YouTube:

```
for (feedEntry in a.feed.entry) {
  if (a.feed.entry.hasOwnProperty(feedEntry)) {
  feedTitle = a.feed.entry[feedEntry].title.$t.replace('] - ', ']').replace(' : ', '').replace(/\(.*?\)/g, "").replace(/\[.*?\]/g, "");
  feedURL = a.feed.entry[feedEntry].link[1].href;
  fragments = feedURL.split("/");
  videoID = fragments[fragments.length - 2];
  url = videoURL + videoID;
  var c = feedTitle.split(' - ');
  tracklist.push({
    'title': c[1],
    'artist': c[0],
    'url': 'http://youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoID + '',
    'album': 'YouTube'
  })
}
```

This code, understandably, causes the browser to freeze a few seconds when loading larger playlists.

What ways could I go about optimizing this?

Comment: You could look at using better [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) as they are _very_ fast.

Comment: and you might want to do this on the server where you have more control - if you are reorganising data into an array all the time, I's vote to let the server do it ( you can cache it in a db )

Comment: @Praveen Oh, thanks! And i was suspecting I should do something about my expressions, but I picked up regexp yesterday so I'm not very good with them.

Answer (score 7):

The freezing comes primarily from the fact that JavaScript is single-threaded so when your loop is busy-looping everything else will wait until the scope has finished before the browser can continue to poll on the event queue.

To solve this you can convert your code to *asynchronous* executing using `setTimeout()` to allow the browser to do other tasks in-between.

Another thing is that `for in` loops are very slow so this can be replaced by using Object keys instead.

Your parsing can be optimized by caching the current object as well as re-factor the parsing itself to a separate function method:

```
var keys = Object.keys(a.feed.entry),  // retrieve all keys from the object
    count = keys.length,               // number of keys to parse
    segment = 10,                      // number to parse each segment
    current;                           // counter for segment

// start loop
(function doSegment() {

    current = segment;                 // reset segment counter for each iteration

    while(current-- && count)
        parseFeedEntry(a.feed.entry[keys[--count]]);

    if (count)
        setTimeout(doSegment, 11);     // delay 11ms to allow browser to breath
})();

function parseFeedEntry(entry) {
    // parse the entry here
    var feedTitle = entry.title.$t.replace('] - ', ']'). ...8X...
    // etc., notice entry is now cached
}
```

### [Online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/GDZ34/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's neat, but the freezing doesn't really affect this situation - I'm more looking to speed up the whole thing, thus I wanted to improve my expressions. Should I create a separate thread for that?

Comment: @JacobPedersen you can't make a separate thread unless you want to involve a web worker. In any case that would probably be slower than direct expression due to the memory copy between the two threads - and a bit overkill for something like this IMO. I'm not an ace at regex so I can't help there (and it wasn't tagged with expressions?). The gain is minimal though and the main issue with the code is the blocking code (for-in loop). The answer above shows a non-blocking approach which will solve that so the expressions themselves won't matter so much really. my 2 cents.

Comment: Alright, will try it out. By "Seperate thread" I meant seperate question :P

Comment: @JacobPedersen aah! :D My head is a bit tired today

Comment: Happens to the best of us :p

Could you point out where/how i should put this? Here's my full function: http://jsfiddle.net/hRP35/

Comment: @JacobPedersen just place it inside the callback (convert callback to an actual function instead of var due to strict mode and scoped functions). I looked at the fiddle but there are many issues in the code and you most likely will run into recursion errors (stack overflow), the variables need to be declared and so forth. If I should implement it for you I would have to debug the whole project which is a bit outside the scope here am I afraid :-/

Comment: Of course it is. This is part of a project I made to learn more about javascript anyways :P I wasn't able to fix any of my code, so I guess I'll leave it as it is until i learn some more about AJAX and XML.

Comment: I found a better solution to the script that retrieves the playlist data, making this far easier (see my own answer). Thanks for the async script and all the help!